# How to group pinned applications that are closed in Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, automation

When you close a pinned application in Windows 7 taskbar, the icon will remain at its place. Leading to a taskbar that contains closed apps, opened apps, closed apps…:

[image]

I would like to group the closed application to the left, like this:

[image]

Of course I can do this manually. But I would like to automate this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the **Don't group** option of [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). Found via [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/39245/any-way-to-ungroup-taskbar-items-in-win7).

Answer (score 0):

It looks less like a mess if you hide labels. I know it's not quite what you're looking for, but check the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/hide-taskbar-labels-without-combining).

Comment: For me hiding the labels would make the matter worse. I'll have hard time figuring which app is running or not, and it's not rare to have many instances of the same app.