# How do you move the taskbar entries around separately for one program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I often have a bunch of Chrome windows open in Windows 7, and what I would like is to move one window to the left of the taskbar, one in the middle, one at the right side, with the other programs that are open mixed in between the different Chrome windows. I have the windows ungrouped in the taskbar, so I can see each window separately.

However, when I try to drag one window, they all drag together. Is is possible to move them separately, one per window?

Comment: Don't think there's a way without some third party software or registry hacks.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/39245/any-way-to-ungroup-taskbar-items-in-windows-7

Answer (score 8):

For those coming here for the same reason as the poster, I'd like to give my recommendation to

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)

It is a versatile taskbar tool which lets you 'unstick' same applications on the taskbar along with many other features. My track record with 7+ Taskbar Tweaker is long, I've previously used it on Windows 7 and now on Windows 10 and it's still my favourite tool. It's consistently low-memory usage; as we speak, it's using 2.3mb.

It's many features are: 
[image]

Disclaimer: I'm in no shape or form affiliated with the guy who makes it, I just think it's a niftly little tool.

Comment: I have used this tool with Windows 7/10, but now in Windows 11 it does not work. Any other tools that can allow re-ordering of windows in the task bar?

Comment: @DDRRSS If you're okay with using the Windows 10 taskbar in Windows 11 then it's possible, if a little bothersome, to use 7+ taskbar tweaker (see [link](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-on-windows-11-with-windows-10s-taskbar) for more info). Apparently, the taskbar in Win 11 requires all the functionality to be re-written from scratch so it's apparently not going to happen any time soon (if ever).

Answer (score 4):

From Windows Help topic "Rearrange icons on the taskbar":

> "All open files from the same program are always grouped together,
>   even if you didn't open them one after the other. This is so all
>   previews for an open program can be viewed together at the same time."

So no, it is not possible to move them separately, without the use of some form of third-party software.

Actually, making multiple copies of Chrome.exe with different names might work, though you might have to tweak some other parameters of the file besides filename. If Windows doesn't know they're the same program, it won't group the icons. However, even if you did get this to work, it might also cause some unintended side effects with browser history, extensions, cookies, etc.