# How do I ungroup taskbar icons in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I've done a Google search about this, and it seems like every single answer to this question refers to Windows 7. I have yet to find a single one that discusses the same problem in Windows 8, as multiple taskbar icons of the same size when the "Never combine" option are set are still stick together and cannot move independently.

Here is the [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/39245/any-way-to-ungroup-taskbar-items-in-windows-7) for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it appears that [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) works in Windows 8 as well. But you'd never know without looking closely.