# Separated icons in the windows task bar for the same software

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

In Windows 7, how to make two windows from the same application to be separated in the task bar ? 
So when i drag one the other stay in place.
For example, opening two windows in Firefox, I want to drag the first to change its position so the second stays in place.

By the way, we didn't have that behavior in Windows Xp !

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that this function is not available in a native Windows 7 operating system.  However, if you really want that capability [there is a third-party application](https://superuser.com/q/39245/650163) that you can install.

Comment: When an existing answer to an existing question, answers a new question like this, the proper thing to do is flag it as a duplicate.  An answer which simply points to another answer, is not really helpful, since the answer you link to could in theory be deleted in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the added perspective.  I have yet to flag a potential duplicate question before now, but will certainly keep that in mind moving forward.