# Windows 7: Close on middle-click of taskbar icon?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, taskbar

I'm used to middle-clicking tabs in Firefox, and finding myself instinctively middle-clicking taskbar icons, expecting it to close them, and annoyed when it opens a new instance instead. Is there something that can make this happen?

Comment: It has exactly that behaviour, just move to the preview and then click with the middle button. There are a lots of mouse and hotkeys shortcuts, see de Windows help for more information. Some other useful hotkeys are by example: ctrl+shift+click: launch elevated, shift+click:launch a new instance, ctrl+click:go to the most recently used windows of the aplication clicked, etc, etc.

Comment: @voodoomsr - please post this as an answer.

Comment: @voodoomsr Thanks, that helps but clicking on the actual icon not the preview would be much preferable.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7?rq=1 (2009)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing programs with middle-click in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7)

Comment: For Windows 11 see https://superuser.com/q/1709896/269897

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the very nice things that **7 Taskbar Tweaker** can do is "Middle Click -> Close".

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

(Throw that man a bone!  Here is a man who takes many of the idiocies that MS has thrown onto us & brings some common sense & thought to the table.  MS should really pay him for his fixes.)