# Close window by middle-clicking the title in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I'm looking for a feature that will close the window by middle-clicking the window's title. It would be nice if I could do that in Windows 7.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7

Comment: @IanBoyd Thank you. It is about `middle clicking` on taskbar not on the title though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing programs with middle-click in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Several years ago, “evl” posted [a script](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=8434#p50920) that does exactly what you want:

> Middle click sends a normal middle click unless:
>
> - Over the taskbar: Closes the window whose button is under the mouse (aborts if window prompts to save,etc).
> - Over the titlebar of a window: closes the window (can be made more sensitive to specific window areas - see Shimanov's post:
>     http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8486).
> - Over an internet explorer class window: Opens a link in a new window (keep holding the button down to switch back to the original window).

You can run it as a script or [compile](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) it to be run as a background program.

Comment: I've just tested with my Windows 7 that doing so is to clone the application window as a native feature. It would be nice to add Ctrl key to the script - but I don't know how to change it. Please help

Comment: *Clone*? It works fine for me, so I’m not sure what the problem is. It is written so that it closes a window when you middle-click its taskbar button or its titlebar, and the only other thing is for IE windows; it opens their links in a new window. Is that where you are seeing the “cloning”? In IE or every window? For example, does happen with Notepad?

Comment: You can cut out the IE code by removing the block starting with `; Open IE link in new window` as well as the block starting with `OpenIELinkInNewWindowSleep:`. Also, you can make it only work when `Ctrl` is held down by changing the first line from `MButton::` to `^MButton::`.

Comment: My apologise. I did a mistake; instead of testing on a windows, I test on the taskbar. So please ignore my comment. Sorry again!

Comment: I've checked your answer as accepted - but `autohotkey` has a trojan as scanned by virustotal.com https://www.virustotal.com/file/4311c3e7c29ed2d67f415138360210bc2f55ff78758b20b003b91d775ee207b9/analysis/

Comment: @NamG.VU, it shouldn’t. Where did you get it from? I just checked the (portable) copy I have from the [official page](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and [it is clean](https://www.virustotal.com/file/de2690282ceadbfd098d54c6dec9f8e810b4435816dbea56d9c99d3aad2c3ec8/analysis/).

Comment: I get it from the link you given in you answer going to http://www.autohotkey.com/ and hit download which will lead to http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkeyInstall.exe

Comment: Except for a single false positive, that’s [clean too](https://www.virustotal.com/file/4311c3e7c29ed2d67f415138360210bc2f55ff78758b20b003b91d775ee207b9/analysis/). If you’re extra paranoid about the installer, you can get the [portable version](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip) instead which is [completely clean](https://www.virustotal.com/file/de2690282ceadbfd098d54c6dec9f8e810b4435816dbea56d9c99d3aad2c3ec8/analysis/).

Comment: Just raise the scan result to notice us about it. The tool is cool. I'll go for the mobile version then. Thanks again Synetech