# shortcut to click and close things on taskbar with one click and no mouse movement?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

My taskbar even with a width to handle two rows, is getting a bit full.

I have put a black circle around what i'd like to quickly close.

I don't want to have to go to each one, right click then move to "close all windows" and left click.  I want like maybe ctrl-alt-click to just close all windows of that which I clicked.
[image]

**Edited for clarification**
Moving through the taskbar manually with arrow keys is very inefficient and only useful when one has no mouse.

I want to move the mouse manually to point to which icon's windows I want to close, then one Click/some combo, and close all of them.  I guess the best i have so far is right click, up, enter.

Comment: Isn't this good enough? http://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7

Comment: @m4573r laptop, no middle click

Comment: @barlop - Update your question to reflect that fact. I assume you can't use an external USB mouse? You could also use AutoHotKey to assign the behavior if both the Left and Right buttons are clicked.  If you have a Synaptics touchpad the Synaptics software can also be used to define a middle mouse button.

Comment: @Ramhound my mouse button like a see saw i.e. one button, it can't do left n right simultaneously, it's either or.

Comment: http://www.ocellated.com/2009/06/04/taskbar-overlord/  I notice this guy mentioned ahk and shift-right click, c. that combo will suffice for now and I suppose his script can be adjusted.

Comment: use ALT + TAB to scroll between the open programs on the taskbar. Then press ALT + F4 to close the ones you want to close.

Comment: @AntoOswin no anto, that is not what i'm looking for. see the question

Answer (score 0):

Only with one key, only softwares or tweakers like [https://superuser.com/questions/24149/...](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7) can only do. But with some Windows shortcuts you can do it with:-
**Windows button + T** ->
**then press right button as you start with the left most application** -> **then press right click menu button (between Alt and Ctrl) and then close any windows with any no. of windows.**

Hope this might help.

Comment: can you clarify this part? "-> then press alt and then close any windows with any no. of windows."

Comment: sorry not Alt but a button between Alt and CTRL on left.When you press right and reach the program (for e.g. if chrome is opened it will be shown in the task-bar and assume that it is on 4 no from the left so you will press right 3 times to reach it) and when you do press that button and you will get the right click menu. (it's called context menu button)

Comment: the button that gets the context menu.. and can do up enter to close. But flicking left and right through the icons with arrow keys is not convenient at all. and you can't even go up and down. it's a shortcut but far fro/m a key combo, not convenient.

Comment: I want to use the mouse to point to what I want. i've edited the question now to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

move the mouse to the taskbar icon, then this click and key combo - right click the taskbar icon, then up arrow(gets the 'close window' or 'close all windows' item) then enter. (i'm talking the right click menu, jump menu, rather than the shift right click one, though the latter works too. )