# Windows 10: Middle-click a Taskbar icon to close that program

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

Is there a way to configure Windows 10 to, upon a middle-click of a program's taskbar icon, close that program, instead of opening a new copy of that program?

I'd prefer a "native" solution (involving no 3rd-party software), but if that's not possible, a 3rd-party software solution would be acceptable.

(Note: Same question as [Closing programs with middle-click in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7?rq=1), but I'm interested in Windows 10 rather than Windows 7.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing programs with middle-click in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7)

Comment: For Windows 11 see https://superuser.com/q/1709896/269897

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3rd-party utility program [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) has been updated to work with Windows 10 (including the mid-2016 "Anniversary Update").  Among other features, it supports configuring a middle-click on a taskbar icon to close that program.

Comment: With Windows' 2017 "Creators Update" it's broken again.

Comment: It works now (Win10 version 17134.285).