# Closing programs with middle-click in Windows 11 taskbar

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/24149/closing-programs-with-middle-click-in-windows-7-10), but for Windows 11.

Is this possible? I want to close programs in the taskbar with middle-click, like tabs in Firefox.

Comment: This is not a Windows 11 feature. You need a third party app if one exists.

Comment: Any recommendation for a third party app that isn't a full taskbar replacement?

Comment: I have not seen such an app. So far as I know, no such thing in Windows 11 (I have been using Windows 11 since July 2021)

Comment: [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) could do this (and many other things) on Windows 10, not tried it on 11 yet and there is no mention of it on their site but it might be worth looking into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it can be done with Windhawk:

- Download Windhawk from https://windhawk.net/ and install it
- Install a mod called [Middle click to close on the taskbar](https://windhawk.net/mods/taskbar-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to try Windhawk but it's 120Mb plus addon module just for a middle-click close option.

Turns out 7tt still works on Windows 11, and works in conjunction with StartIsBack so I can have ungrouped, uncombined taskbar items that I can close with a three-finger tap of my trackpad (or middle mouse button)

Comment: 120MB on disk, so what? It takes less than 1MB in memory when running in the background. Also, it can do more than a middle-click close, there are other modules you might want to use.